# Can tests with pytest fixtures be run interactively?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some tests written using pytest and fixtures, e.g.:

```
class TestThing:
    @pytest.fixture()
    def temp_dir(self, request):
        my_temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        def fin():
            shutil.rmtree(my_temp_dir)
        request.addfinalizer(fin)
        return my_temp_dir
    def test_something(self, temp_dir)
        with open(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'test.txt'), 'w') as f:
            f.write('test')
```

This works fine when the tests are invoked from the shell, e.g.

```
 $ py.test
```

but I don't know how to run them from within a python/ipython session; trying e.g.

```
tt = TestThing()
tt.test_something(tt.temp_dir())
```

fails because `temp_dir` requires a `request` object to be passed on.  So, how does one invoke a fixture with a `request` object injected?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands

Leads me to believe you can just prefix it with ! (as in `!py.test`) should work in iPython...

Comment: Running `py.test` requires that you be in the directory containing the test script, which largely defeats the purpose.  Also, though, it denies you access to the traceback and the python interactive debugger, which is the real purpose of running the functions directly and interactively.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Sorry about that.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739098/4752883

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You don't have to manually assemble any test fixtures or anything like that. Everything runs just like calling `pytest` in the project directory.

### Method1:

This is the best method because it gives you access to the debugger if your test fails

In `ipython` shell use:

`**ipython**> run -m pytest prj/`

This will run all your tests in the `prj/tests` directory.

This will give you access to the debugger, or allow you to set `breakpoints` if you have a 
`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in your program (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#setting-breakpoints).

### Method2:

Use `!pytest` while in the test directory. This wont give you access to the debugger. However, if you use

`**ipython**> !pytest --pdb`

If you have a test failure, it will drop you into the debugger (subshell), so you can run your post-mortem analysis  (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures)

---

Using these methods you can even run individual modules/test_fuctions/TestClasses in `ipython` using (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests)

`**ipython**> run -m pytest prj/tests/test_module1.py::TestClass1::test_function1`

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the pytest.fixture decorator and directly call the wrapped test function.

```
tmp = tt.temp_dir.__pytest_wrapped__.obj(request=...)
```

Accessing internals, it's bad, but when you need it...

Answer (score 0):

The best method I have which is far from ideal is to just %run the test file, then manually assemble the fixtures, then simply call the tests. The problem with this is tracking down the modules where the default fixtures are defined, and then calling them in their order of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two cells for this:

first:

```
def test_something():
    assert True
```

second:

```
from tempfile import mktemp
test_file = mktemp('.py', 'test_')
open(test_file, 'wb').write(_i) # write last cell input

!pytest $test_file
```

also u can do this on one cell like this but you won't have code highlighting:

```
from tempfile import mktemp

test_code = """
def test_something():
    assert True
"""

test_file = mktemp('.py', 'test_')
open(test_file, 'wb').write(test_code)

!pytest $test_file
```

Answer (score -3):

The simple answer is that you don't want to run py.test interactively from python.  Most people set up some integration with their text editor or IDE to run py.test and parse it's output.  But really it's a command line tool and that is how it should be used.

As a sidenode you may want to check out the built-in `tmpdir` fixture: http://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html  Because it seems like you're re-inventing this.

Comment: It would be very nice / convenient / time-saving to run individual tests from IPython while adding and debugging tests.

Comment: You can do this. See below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739098/4752883

Comment: This isn't accurate, so I'd prefer it just be removed.