# IPython shortcut for importing pytest fixtures

Tags: ipython, pytest, ipython-magic

Suppose that I am writing a test called `test_this_thing` in IPython which I intend to progressively save into a test file `test_some_tests.py`.

When it comes to *running* my tests I can do that easily from IPython with this great suggestion from a colleague:

```
%run -m pytest -- -k test_this_thing
```

Suppose I added a couple of fixtures into my test file (marked with `@pytest.fixture`). To get them into my IPython REPL I have to import them and call them (since they are written as functions):

```
from test_some_tests import *

fixture1 = fixture1()
fixture2 = fixture2()
```

I wonder if there is any kind of way to leverage pytest's fixture-finding functionality to write an IPython magic function like:

```
%import_fixtures -k test_this_thing
```

which would import into my IPython all the fixtures that the `-k test_this_thing` tests need and do the `f = f()` bit for me on each of them?

**Note**: When I write tests in IPython I will usually be running it from the directory where my test file lives (ie I `cd` into that directory before running `ipython`), so that

```
from test_some_tests import *
```

works. Some people might add various `__init__.py` to make their tests importable but I tend not to (indeed, IIRC the pytest suggestion is to *not* do that).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739098/2641825 suggests starting an ipython shell within the package directory and then running `!pytest --pdb` to enter inside the function that is causing a test to fail. Objects in that function can then be inspected at the [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an alternative which works and which brings one advantage -- it imports my underscore helper functions too.

At the bottom of the test file I added:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fixture1 = fixture1()
    fixture2 = fixture2()
```

and then in IPython, rather than

```
from test_some_tests import *
```

I do

```
%run test_some_tests.py
```

The advantage is that this also imports into IPython all my underscore helper functions.